# Flex/CSS cannot align text in the center of the div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
    html{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    body{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    #board {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 600px;
        width: 600px;
        justify-content: stretch;
        align-items: stretch;
    }

    #board .row{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: stretch;
        align-items: stretch;
        flex: 1;
    }

    .square {
        background-color: red;
        border: white solid 1px;
        flex: 1;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    #board .row .square:hover{
        background-color: yellow;
    }


    .square:hover:before
    {
       content: "O";
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="board">

            <div class = "row" >
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
            </div>

            <div class = "row" >
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
            </div>

            <div class = "row">
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
            </div>

       </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Hello,very short question.

Just started to use Flex/CSS. Cannot solve a problem.

Why does Flex align-items:center and justify-content:center does not put the text in the center of the div. What is the proper way to put the text in the center of the parent div. It should have placed the "O" right into the center of the parent div.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add     `display: flex;` to the parent div. (`.square` in your case)

Comment: Thanks for noticing)

Answer (score 0):

a quick fix for css:

```
html{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#board {      

    display: flex;
    justify-content: stretch;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#board .row{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}

.square {
    background-color: red;
    border: white solid 1px;
    flex: 1;   
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#board .row .square:hover{
    background-color: yellow;
}

.row .square:hover:before
{
  content: "O";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    html{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    body{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    #board {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 600px;
        width: 600px;
        justify-content: stretch;
        align-items: stretch;
    }

    #board .row{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: stretch;
        align-items: stretch;
        flex: 1;
    }

    .square {
        /* just add this line */
        display: flex;
        background-color: red;
        border: white solid 1px;
        flex: 1;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    #board .row .square:hover{
        background-color: yellow;
    }


    .square:hover:before
    {
       content: "O";
       
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="board">

            <div class = "row" >
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
            </div>

            <div class = "row" >
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
            </div>

            <div class = "row">
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
                <div class="square"></div>
            </div>

       </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Just add `display: flex` in the `.square` class that'll row-wise center (default) your content, but if say you want to column-wise center you just need to do `flex-direction: column;` in the `.square` class.